# undefined error in layerslider (wordpress cms)

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, layer

hello my friend i have latest wordpress and install layerslider version 6.8.4 , slider work fine but in gtmetrix show me undefined load error page when i have disable this plugin error gone but when enable it error sill problem. however , how can i fix that ?

```
if(typeof lsjQuery.fn.layerSlider == "undefined")
```

[that picture of gtmetrix results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuF3v.png)